# Connect to Jupyter Notebooks launched from Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I have followed a number of tutorials and I keep getting the same issue would appreciate some help.  The steps I am taking.

1) Create an instance - (to avoid having to redownload anaconda or jupyter notebooks one can use as image one of the images with Tensor Flow or Pytorch e.g. Deep Learning Image: TensorFlow 1.15.0 m40). Make sure to click allow under the Firewalls Section: Allow HTTP traffic and HTTPS traffic.

2) View Network Details:

2.1) Firewall Rules: Create a firewall rule, priority: 1000, Direction: Egress, IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 Protocols and ports: tcp:8888

2.2) External IP address make sure it is of type static

Next Launch VM instance

Once in the VM instance:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser
```

you may also create a jupyter notebook config file which should look something like this:
to create the file:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Config file:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Once it is launched you should simply be able to enter

http://[external-ip]:8888

where the external-ip is in the form XX.XXX.XX.XXX

and you will be connected to notebook

ps: The 8888 is a placeholder in theory anything should work. I advise trying to change it if it does not.

I do all of the following and am not able to connect. Where not being able to connect means that I get a connection timeout as if the server did not exist:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> XX.XXX.XX.XXX took to long to respond

. Would appreciate some guidance on how to debug this or if there is something I am doing that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your firewall rule to allow traffic on Ingress.